# Receiving strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given error in php

Tags: php, date, laravel

The program works fine when I pass the array like following:

```
$holidays=array("2015-01-01","2015-01-05","2015-01-10");

echo getWorkingDays("2015-01-02","2015-01-09",$holidays);
```

But when I extract the data from database like this:

```
$holidays = DB::table('tbl_holiday')->select('holiday_date')->whereBetween('holiday_date', array('2015-01-01', '2015-01-20'))->get();
```

I am getting this error: **strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given**

In my helpers.php, I have this code

```
 foreach($holidays as $holiday){

       $time_stamp=strtotime($holiday);

      //If the holiday doesn't fall in weekend
      if ($startDate <= $time_stamp && $time_stamp <= $endDate && date("N",$time_stamp) != 6 )
      $workingDays--;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Might be worth looking at this:  http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.datetime.date-holidays.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get the actual datestring from `$holiday`

```
$timestamp = strtotime($holiday->holiday_date);
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the database query, your `$holidays` variable is an array of stdClass objects. If you want an array that contains just the `holiday_date` values, you can use the `lists()` method, instead of `get()`:

```
$holidays = DB::table('tbl_holiday')
    ->whereBetween('holiday_date', array('2015-01-01', '2015-01-20'))
    ->lists('holiday_date');
```